# Выставление флага CF при вычитании

Tags: ассемблер

Правильны ли мои мысли: флаг переноса выставляется при вычитании из меньшего большего. Например :

```
mov eax ,1
cmp eax,2
jb truWay
```

В двоичном виде:
1=00000001
2=00000010=11111101+1(доп код)=11111110

и 00000001+11111110=11111111 -Почему выставляется флаг переноса? Ведь самого переноса нет... или я неправ?

Comment: Самое важное: числа по битам хранятся в таком виде, что сложение и вычитание выполняет одна и та же схема (микрокод), вне зависимости от того, это число со знаком или нет. То есть, процессор не знает, вычитает он знаковые числа или беззнаковые, и просто при определенных условиях выставляет определенные флаги, которые важны для программиста.

Comment: фактически cmp вычитает из первого аргумента второй (без сохранения результата), 1-2=-1. Какова бы ни была разрядность мы переваливаем через 0, а это выставляет флаг переноса

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0